# Ruby on Rails--submitt button and page is as wide as web page

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following the ruby-on-rails tutorial by Micheal Hartl

I've gotten to the sign-up page layout part( 7.22, listing 7.19>> http://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up)

But the things is my page displays oddly, the submit button is as wide as the web page not to mention the whole form as well.

I checked the code and it is the same as the book states, the only difference is I changed "$grayLighter" to "$gray-light" as "$grayLighter" I believe is depreciated.

Here is my custom.css.scss

```
 input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
  }

   input {
    height: auto !important;
  }
```

Here is my
app/views/users/new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your `app/views/users/new.html.erb` look like?

Comment: look up bootstrap 3 grid system.. it has changed from bootstrap 2

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I have run into recently is that the CSS is pulled in during the :precompile stage of the build.  So when I make CSS changes, I have to remember to build the app, or bounce the host its on so it pulls in any CSS changes during the :precompile.

What I do to test is to put the CSS on the top of the html.erb page in  brackets.

This allows me to test the CSS with a simple page refresh on my browser.  Once I have that working and I know it looks good.  Then I copy that CSS to the relevant CSS file and build it to test it again.

Not sure if this is your issue or not, but I know it messed with me.

Comment: I've tried re-starting the server, but the pages still displays the button and text area's too wide.

Comment: I would try adding your CSS to your html.erb page like I suggested above.  If it works there, then the issue could be a few different things.  First we want to nail down the CSS and get it working though.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap3, span6 offset3 doesn't work.
try this :

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
```